# probabilistic interpretation of eigenvalues of the Laplacian

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation, stochastic-differential-equations

> Problem: Let $D \subset \mathbf{R}^n$ be open, bounded and let $\lambda \in \mathbf{R}$.
> a) Suppose there exists a solution $u \in C^2(D) \cap C(\bar{D}), u$ not identically zero, such that
> $$
> \left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
> -\frac{1}{2} \Delta u=\lambda u & \text { in } & D \\
> u=0 & \text { on } & \partial D
> \end{array}\right.
> $$
> Then $\lambda>0$.
> b) It can be shown that if $D$ is smooth then there exist $0<\lambda_0<\lambda_1<$ $\cdots<\lambda_n<\cdots$ where $\lambda_n \rightarrow \infty$ such that condition holds for $\lambda=\lambda_n$, $n=0,1,2, \ldots$, and for no other values of $\lambda$. The numbers $\left\{\lambda_n\right\}$ are called the eigenvalues of the operator $-\frac{1}{2} \Delta$ in the domain $D$ and the corresponding (nontrivial) solutions $u_n$ of condition are called the eigenfunctions.
>
> 1). Put $\tau=\tau_D=\inf \left\{t>0 ; B_t \notin D\right\}$, choose $\rho>0$ and define
> $$
> w_\rho(x)=E^x[\exp (\rho \tau)] ; \quad x \in D .
> $$
> Prove that if $w_\rho(x)<\infty$ for all $x \in D$ then $\rho$ is not an eigenvalue for $-\frac{1}{2} \Delta$.
> 2). Conclude that
> $$
> \lambda_0 \geq \sup \left\{\rho ; E^x[\exp (\rho \tau)]<\infty \text { for all } x \in D\right\} .
> $$

For 1).Let u be a solution with $\lambda=\rho$. Applying Dynkin's formula to the process $d(Y_t)=(dt,dB_t)$ and the function $f(t,x)=e^{\rho t}u(x)$, we get $$E^{(t,x)}[f(Y_{\tau \wedge n})]=f(t,x)+E^{(t,x)}[\int_0^{\tau \wedge n} Lf(Y_s) ds]$$. Since $$Lf(t,x)=\rho e^{\rho t} u(x)+\frac{1}{2}e^{\rho t}\triangle u(x)=0$$, then $$E^{(t,x)}[e^{\rho \tau \wedge n} u(B_{\tau \wedge n})]=e^{\rho t}u(x).$$ Let t=0 and $n \rightarrow \infty$, is it true we have the boundary solution and so $u(x)=0$?

For 2).Since eigenvalues are monotonically increasing and $\lambda_i>0$, we have the claim. Is it right?

Comment: Sorry but what is $B_{\tau}$ and $w_{\rho}$?

Comment: @EtienneBfx edited